# Maven: Handling Builds for Differing source/target Versions

Tags: java, maven, version-control

Two different maven Java projects (let's call them ProjectA and ProjectB) depend on the same library (also a maven Java project, all three projects are self-written). ProjectA needs the library to be compiled for Java 1.7, ProjectB for 1.8. So far I had the following configuration in my library's pom.xml:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.6.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Installing the library like this then allows me to build ProjectB but not ProjectA, as  and  are both set to 1.8. I can change those two fields to 1.7 to allow ProjectA to be built but not B.

I want to do proper version control, automated builds, etc. and hence can't always change the lib's source/target version before building a project. Maintaining two library release branches, so solving the issue via the version control system, is also annoying and does not seem elegant (that's my current approach which I'd like to change).

If I replace the version with a variable (e.g. ${jdk.version}) and use the command line flag -Djdk.version=1.7 when installing the lib ProjectA will, for some reason, still not build, claiming the lib is targeted at 1.8. So apparently this is not equivalent to manually putting the 1.7 into the pom.xml file.

How can one solve this problem elegantly? Why will maven/Java not properly target the library at 1.7 if I try to set the corresponding property via the command line?

Comment: If you compile with 1.7 the Project which uses JDK 8 can use it ? Maybe I misunderstand a thing but that should work ?

Comment: Take a look at maven build profiles: http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html

Comment: @khmarbaise That does sound like a simple solution, I believe there was some issue with the framework used, however, although I cannot recall details right now.

Comment: @Goibniu That looks like exactly the answer I was looking for, thanks!